# MInimum value of the sum of three numbers

Tags: algebra-precalculus, optimization

if product of three numbers is 1, how do you find the minimum value of the sum of those three numbers?

i tried to find the possible values of the numbers that would give a product of one but I'm not sure if that helps in any way. I dont want the solution, i just want to know what method to use in approaching this question and how to check my answer

**Added after looking at comments:** The problem poser clearly intended that the three numbers all be positive.

Comment: If the numbers are  $>0$ use AM GM inequality

Comment: @patrickh can we not have a combination of different decimal numbers being multiplied to give 1? Such as 0.1, .001, 10, 1 and 100 will give 1. Can i not do this with numerous numbers and still get a product of one?

Comment: Write $xyz = 1$. Then $z$ must be nonzero, so we can eliminate it by replacing it with $1/(xy)$. Now you want to minimize $x + y + 1/(xy)$. But we can make this sum as small as we want: for example, $x = y = -n$ for some large positive $n$, and $z = 1/n^2$.

Comment: @amcerbu thanks a lot!, but how do we know the value of n for which this is minimal, because it seems as if we choose n to be any number, we can keep going and the summation keeps going down

Comment: Exactly: there is no minimum value of the sum. We can make it as negative as we want. Perhaps the problem is missing a statement that the numbers should all be positive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let the three numbers be $x,y,z$ and following @amcerbu replace $z = \frac{1}{xy}$.  Then to find a local minimum for 
$$f(x,y) = x+y + \frac{1}{xy}$$ if you know calculus, you do:
$$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = 0 \\\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = 0$$

Solving those equations simultaneously, you get $y^5 = 1$.